# droplevels() messes with table() so as to produce wrong counts

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, r-factor, r-table

I have a large data frame that I'm trying to subset and then table. In order to get rid of unused levels inherited from the superset (the original data frame), I use `droplevels()`, but this somehow messes up the counts in `table()`:

```
#without droplevels()

unknownMun <- table(unknown$MUNICIPALITY_NAME) 
unknownMun <- unknownMun[unknownMun >= 1]

> unknownMun

   Albertslund Kommune        Allerød Kommune       Ballerup Kommune       Bornholm Kommune        Brøndby Kommune         Dragør Kommune         Egedal Kommune 
                14                     32                     88                      9                     30                      3                     18 
 Frederiksberg Kommune  Frederikssund Kommune         Furesø Kommune           Gentofte Kommune       Gladsaxe Kommune       Glostrup Kommune       Gribskov Kommune 
                53                     38                     10                     43                     21                     41                     53 
       Halsnæs Kommune      Helsingør Kommune         Herlev Kommune           Hillerød Kommune       Hvidovre Kommune  Høje-Taastrup Kommune       Hørsholm Kommune 
                80                     23                     46                     35                     22                      2                     70 
Københavns Kommune Lyngby-Taarbæk Kommune      Rudersdal Kommune           
               560                     93                     34
```

If I do the same with `droplevels()`, this is what I get:

```
levels(unknown$MUNICIPALITY_NAME) <- droplevels(unknown$MUNICIPALITY_NAME)

unknownMun <- table(unknown$MUNICIPALITY_NAME)

> unknownMun 

    Københavns Kommune  Frederiksberg Kommune       Glostrup Kommune            Brøndby Kommune        Rødovre Kommune    Albertslund Kommune  Høje-Taastrup Kommune 
                  1440                      0                      0                          0                      0                      0                      0 
  Hvidovre Kommune         Herlev Kommune       Ballerup Kommune         Tårnby Kommune         Dragør Kommune Lyngby-Taarbæk Kommune       Gentofte Kommune 
                 0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0 
 Rudersdal Kommune       Gladsaxe Kommune       Hørsholm Kommune      Helsingør Kommune       Gribskov Kommune        Halsnæs Kommune       Hillerød Kommune 
                 0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0                      0 
   Allerød Kommune         Furesø Kommune  Frederikssund Kommune         Egedal Kommune       Bornholm Kommune 
                 0                      0                      0                      0                      0
```

Can anybody explain what goes wrong here and how to fix it?

I really prefer something like `droplevels()`because the tables get differing lengths when I use the `x[x >= 1]`operator and I'm trying to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`droplevels` works on `data.frames` and `factors` respectively not on the *levels* of the `factor`.

So you should either do:

```
unknown$MUNICIPALITY_NAME <- droplevels(unknown$MUNICIPALITY_NAME)
```

or

```
unknown <- droplevels(unknown)
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be

```
unknown$MUNICIPALITY_NAME <- droplevels(unknown$MUNICIPALITY_NAME)
```

without the call to `levels` on the left-hand side.